# Change in state not affecting other elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have set up a function that handles an onClick event that toggles an icon. The function toggles the icon, affects the state, and changes the class but these things do not apply to the table row.

```
{this.state.company.map((comp, i) =>
    <tr key={i} className={this.state.checked ? 'colored' : 'none'}>
      <td>
         <i className={this.state.checked ? 'bx bxs-checkbox-checked' : 'bx bx-checkbox'} onClick={(e) => this.handleCheck(e,comp.id)}></i>
      </td>
      <td>
         <Link to={`/view/${comp.id}`}>{comp.name}</Link>
      </td>
      <td>{comp.type}@gmail.com</td>
      <td>{comp.id}</td>
      <td>
         <Badge variant="primary">Primary</Badge>
      </td>
   </tr>
)}
```

Basically, I want the background of the table row to change when the icon is toggled.

Comment: Please update your whole code. What is handleCheck function?

Comment: @bkm412 The handleCheck just toggles the state and stores toggled data IDs in an array. the handleCheck is working since the icons are properly toggled and the state "checked" is changed.

Comment: Can you show us how are you updating the state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could you try this .. if you handle state is just that....

```
onClick={(e) => {
            this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })
        }}
```

there maybe something wrong with handleCheck function ...could you post your code for handleCheck

Comment: Thanks for this! Apparently, this function is inside the if statement and the condition for the table rows are inside the else and are not affecting them when the state changes. I have solved the problem by placing this method globally.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the working example here.

[Toggle State](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7abt8j)

Probably you are not setting state in handleClick function.